# compatibility between angular and knockout js code

Tags: angular, knockout.js

I have an existing knockout js application. If i want to integrate a new standalone application coded in angular along. Is it possible to somehow render this angular application in the knockout js application as a part of it.
I need some general ideas as i could not find this type of scenario over the internet.

Comment: "*i could not find this type of scenario over the internet*" because it's highly unusual and highly undesirable. Some frameworks, like KO and Angular, are soft "mutually exclusive". It's not that you can't use both but they overlap to a sufficient extent that you don't need to. Which means that very few ever try to include both at the same time and when that happens, it's for *extremely* edge cases. So, it's nor recommended, and I doubt there is documentation anywhere for how to do it. For your case, though - do you *really* ned to use both? Can't you just render the Angular app in an iframe?

Comment: @VLAZ Yes you are absolutely right. i can go with an iframe but I'm sure you are aware of the disadvantages too, i.e some browsers and devices cannot support it. So  i was moreover thinking maybe there can/must be a way in which i can tweak this angular code into the  KO app. I'm very thankful for your insights for this problematic situation of mine

Comment: I'm not aware of iframes *not* working on any relevant browser, including mobile ones. Also, I'm not sure that there is a device that Angular supports yet cannot use an iframe. It seems like the simplest solution, even though I'm aware that's doesn't mean it is actually *simple* (it won't just take 5 minutes, likely few days). Still, it's better than the alternative. Meshing the two together will get messy as you need to keep the dependencies in check and execution not to trample one another. I'd anticipate weird and hard to diagnose and debug edge cases, too.

Comment: All the reasons people do not mix such frameworks. In short, it just becomes too complex to manage and maintain. An iframe has the advantage of the two applications being kept separate thus simpler to manage. Although at the cost of some infrastructure to support that. Even then, there is no real generic way to include one app into another as an iframe - the *idea* is generic but it depends on what responsibilities the two have. It becomes even harder if the two have to communicate together. So...if possible I'd start with *not* combining anything.

Comment: The two would be hosted separately and users might need to jump from app A to app B and back a lot but at least it's a start. The more advanced idea is an iframe *if possible* and also if it makes sense. This will keep all on one page (from user perspective) and would provide better experience. I'd attempt to combine the two applications directly as a very last resort. None of this is a directly solved problem, though - each approach will need to be tailored to what the requirements and limitations each specific application has, as well as what the overall goal is.

Comment: @VLAZ For the time being I have used iframe to render the angular application. Just like you said it is really the simplest solution. The only possible concern for now will be to maintain the sessions which I think can be taken care of. Thank you very much for your information.